What to set via setsockopt() to receive jumbo frames?
I have a TCP connection and I would like to improve network throughput by receiving Jumbo frames.
My network allows jumbo frames through hosts/routers etc.
What do I need to set via setsockopt() to receive jumbo frames? I have already set my receive buffer size.
I've read setting the MTU only affects the outgoing packet size.

The MTU needs to be set appropriately on the network adapters of both the sending and receiving host.  Use wireshark / tcpdump to verify the size of the packets on the wire.

Also note that you won't see individual TCP packets with a TCP socket.  You instead get a stream of bytes.

All the routers in the path will also need to have a sufficient MTU for these jumbo frames. If you're communicating over the public Internet, you don't have any control over this.


What do I need to set via setsockopt() to receive jumbo frames?

Nothing, because there is no socket option available for that feature.  Jumbo frames are handed by the networking hardware at the Ethernet level, not by your application.  If your networking adapter, your LAN router, your WAN modem, etc support Jumbo Frames, if it is enabled in the hardware settings, the MTU size is configured accordingly, then they will exchange larger frames automatically.

"the MTU size is configured accordingly" who/what needs to configure this? Do you mean on each router in the network?

@intrigued_66 "Do you mean on each router in the network?" - yes. And as this is not a programming issue anymore, try asking in Network Engineering or maybe [sf].
